# How should you model a database to store prices having varied frequency minutes, hours, days and months

Tags: database-design, time-series, modeling, cryptocurrency

I am trying to model a table which will store prices of a particular currency both historical and current with prices coming in varied time intervals such as minutes, hours and month.

My access pattern would be like to get pricing in minutes for last 24hrs or to get prices in hours for last 30 days or to get prices in days for last 1 year.

How should I model my table, should I use different table for storing each kind of interval or should I dump in one table and categorize using a label field. What are the strategies used by various listing sites?

Comment: My inclination would be to use one table with a timestamp and label.  I can see using three separate tables.  I have no strong feelings either way.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the data you're trying to model - could you provide some examples?

Answer (score 0):

You could indeed have a label field to indicate the type of data you are dealing with.
However, I suppose that you can obtain the monthly data from the hourly data, for instance, i.e. the different frequencies can be calculated from the ground up via resampling or window functions.
If that is the case, you could store the data at the most granular level and use Pandas built-in [`resample()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) or [`rolling()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) window to calculate the daily, weekly, and monthly prices.